# pdf-tools: View multiple pages in one buffer - like evince's continous mode

Tags: pdf-tools

pdf-tools shows by default just one page in the buffer at once. How can it be configured, that it displays multiple pages below each other just like evince does in "continuous" mode, if the zoom factor is small enough such that (parts) of multiple pages fit on one page?

Comment: Follow the (currently nonexistent) progress on https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/27

Comment: A [dirty hack](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/27#issuecomment-696237353) has been posted in [issue #27](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/27) now

Answer (score 12):

It can't do that.  I have some ideas about how to implement this, but nothing has materialized yet.

Comment: any updates on that?