# Is there continuous scrolling and double page viewing in pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf-tools

pdf-tools jumps from the end of one page to the next page. Is there a ways to activate some kind of smooth scrolling? Also is there a way to display a double sided layout on my screen?

Comment: Answer to first question is no: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/pdf-tools-view-multiple-pages-in-one-buffer-like-evinces-continous-mode?rq=1

Comment: Maybe the dirty hack in `pdf-continuous-scroll.el` which can be found [here](https://github.com/dalanicolai/dala-emacs-lisp) is useful. More information about its usage can be found [here](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/27#issuecomment-696237353)

Answer (score 5):

Currently, this is not possible. Several feature requests have been submitted on the project's GitHub page: [Feature request: continuous view #27](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/27), and more recently, [Double pages layout #303](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/303).

Apparently, this will not be fixed soon, quoting the package author in one of his replies to issue #27:

> Generally speaking, there are two issues:
>
> - Large parts of the software (including image-mode) assume a one-to-one correspondence between a displayed page and its window.
> - Emacs is not easily convinced to scroll an image, such that its display starts in the middle of it, in case would completely fits into the window.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but there is a fix that works for me, see here: https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/55

The second-to-last post has a fix which works for me. Place the functions somewhere in your Emacs config and bind them to `C-M-v` or `C-M-S-v` respectively.

Not a pretty hack, but works so far for me - at least with pdf-tools.

Comment: I think the specific comment is that is being referred to is [this](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/55#issuecomment-230108362)

Answer (score 1):

This package does that https://github.com/dalanicolai/pdf-continuous-scroll-mode.el

Since it is not available in melpa **use-package** can not be used, but the following elisp will first install quelpa and then install the package.

(use-package quelpa
:ensure t)

```
(use-package pdf-tools
  :ensure t
  :config
  (pdf-tools-install t)
  (quelpa '(pdf-continuous-scroll-mode
          :fetcher github
          :repo "dalanicolai/pdf-continuous-scroll-mode.el"))

  (add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook 'pdf-continuous-scroll-mode))
```