# pdf-tools view bottom of one page and top of another page simulatenously

Tags: pdf-tools

Does pdf-tools have scrolling where I can view the bottom half of one pdf page and the top of the next page? Right now, my installation simply jumps to the next page and I cannot view two pages simultaneously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there continuous scrolling and double page viewing in pdf-tools?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33433/is-there-continuous-scrolling-and-double-page-viewing-in-pdf-tools)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pdf-tools: View multiple pages in one buffer - like evince's continous mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26762/pdf-tools-view-multiple-pages-in-one-buffer-like-evinces-continous-mode)

Comment: Thanks for the two comments. Unfortunately, the proposed fix does not allow viewing two pages simultaneously. It only allows smooth scrolling to jump to the next page, and once it jumps to the next page, it does not show the previous page

Comment: @Vikram Yes, that's what the two other answers and the linked `pdf-tools` issues say - neither Emacs nor `pdf-tools` currently supports what you are asking for.

Comment: If I display the same PDF buffer in two windows I can display different pages of the PDF in each window, including showing the bottom of one page and the top of the next.  It's not automated (I'd expect `follow-mode` to be the entry point if it were, and that doesn't work), but clearly in 2023 it's at least *possible* to get the display you're after.

Answer (score 1):

The package [pdf-continuous-scroll](https://github.com/dalanicolai/pdf-continuous-scroll-mode.el) provides this functionality. It is hacky (and therefore it is not on (M)ELPA), but it does a reasonable job...